# How to remove only the update button on sonata admin edit?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I need to remove only the edit button (`Atualizar`) on the edit of a Sonata Admin:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btn_update_and_edit"><i class="fa fa-save" 
aria-hidden="true"></i> Atualizar</button>
```

But I need to keep the update and list (`Atualizar e sair`) option:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btn_update_and_list"><i class="fa fa-save"
></i> <i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i> Atualizar e sair</button>
```

I could probably remove it with JavaScript by subscribing the template, but it does not seen to be the best approach.

[image: options on sdit form]

Answer (score 3):

If you need hide this "Update" button for all edit pages then, a solution would be override the `base_edit_form.html.twig` template and its `sonata_form_actions` block, which contains this part.

Make sure to create a new template with the same name of the origin template file in this path:

```
- app/
  - Resources/
    - SonataAdminBundle/
      - views/
        - CRUD/
            base_edit_form.html.twig
```

and overrides this block with the needed changes:

```
{% use '@SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_edit_form.html.twig' %}

{% block sonata_form_actions %} 
    ...
{% endblock %}
```

**Note:** Use `formactions` block name for oldest version if `sonata_form_actions` is not defined.

More about ["How to Override Templates from Third-Party Bundles" here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/overriding.html).

Comment: I'd also mention that the "sonata_form_actions" block may be called differently depending on one's AdminBundle version. "formactions" is (I think) the name for it in older versions. Just a heads up.

Comment: @StasParshin note added! Thanks!

Comment: I need this just for one page

Comment: @RafaelMansilhaMurta if you need this just for one page, use the 2nd part of the answer only for your page.

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't work on my side. I did the exact some thing and nothing changes.